# Substrate recipe basic-pow doesn't mine blocks?

Tags: substrate

I compiled the latest version of the node "basic-pow" from the substrate recipes, run the node using the command "./basic-pow --alice" so i have the authority role, but it never produces blocks, it prepared the first block but never imported it and that's it! Any idea how to debug this issue?!

```
2021-04-22 02:01:50  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0xb9dc…acca), finalized #0 (0xb9dc…acca), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2021-04-22 02:01:55  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0xb9dc…acca), finalized #0 (0xb9dc…acca), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
2021-04-22 02:01:55  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0xb9dc9e35f56e7ffa61dda014752ebf87015bf74bcb58c9538e55ce0a3f6eacca    
2021-04-22 02:01:55  Prepared block for proposing at 1 [hash: 0x8aab6b009ed4f548d0bb49eedf042177005c387898594707647f1a02209dfc93; parent_hash: 0xb9dc…acca; extrinsics (1): [0x8176…4bd3]]    
2021-04-22 02:02:00  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0xb9dc…acca), finalized #0 (0xb9dc…acca), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2021-04-22 02:02:05  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0xb9dc…acca), finalized #0 (0xb9dc…acca), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2021-04-22 02:02:10  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0xb9dc…acca), finalized #0 (0xb9dc…acca), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
```

***Using substrate 3.0:***
**Node Name**: basic-pow
**Node Version**: 3.0.0
**Commit**: commit 53f7ce1 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Author: Joshy Orndorff JoshOrndorff@users.noreply.github.com Date: Wed Apr 14 23:53:04 2021 -0400
**Cargo Version**: cargo 1.49.0-nightly (dd83ae55c 2020-10-20)
**Rustup**: rustc 1.49.0-nightly (ffa2e7ae8 2020-10-24)
**OS**: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

***Using substrate 2.0:***
**Node Name**: basic-pow
**Node Version**: 2.0.0
**Commit**: commit a8f6e741b1bf6564d5f3713723f2b5f8ed2e9f31 (HEAD) Author: Jimmy Chu jimmy@parity.io Date: Thu Oct 1 16:45:56 2020 +0800
**Cargo Version**: cargo 1.48.0-nightly (05c611ae3 2020-09-23)
**Rustup**: rustc 1.48.0-nightly (ef663a8a4 2020-09-30)
**OS**: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to this ticket on Github https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/recipes/issues/432, it is confirmed broken.

// edit:
A basic solution was added to the ticket.